# Regexp replacement only between tags

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this text:

```
Some text here.
bla bla bla
<myTag>
   m_Member1 blah blah
   m_Member2 blah
   m_Member3 foo bar blah
<end>
Other text here...
bla bla.
```

I want to replace `m_Member1`, `m_Member2`, ... by `Member1`,`Member2` but only between `<myTag>` and `<end>`.

I know how to replace `m_Member1`... in the whole document with regexp:

search: `(_|\t)+(m_)`

replace by: `\1\3`

It works well. But I want to do this only between `<myTag>` and `<end>`

Comment: This sounds like you're try to parse HTML with regex. [**TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1954610)

Comment: You could probably hack something together with look-arounds, but it's going to be a very complex and imperfect solution ... Alternatively if you could just parse the XML/HTML/whatever those tags are supposed to be (using an actual parser), the problem becomes quite simple.

Comment: As you can see, it's not exactly the case because <myTag> has no closing html-like tag. The closing tag is another tag : <end>

Comment: Do you have only one `<myTag>` in your document or many?

Comment: @coutiereric *"<myTag> has no closing html-like tag"* -- That's true, but I somewhat assumed you're showing pseudo-code, rather than necessarily a correct representative example of this markup language. Regardless though, is there some way you could **parse** the markup rather than trying to hack it with regex?

Comment: Since you tagged your question _notepad++_, why not first search for `<myTag>`, then do replace `m_Member` with `Member` and then keep hitting _Replace_ button until you see that you have reached `<end>`?

Comment: Is that a log sample or a programming script? A lexer would be the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:<myTag>|\G).*?\K\bm_(?=Member\d+(?:(?!<myTag>).)*?<end>)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                 # non capture group
    <myTag>             # open tag
  |                   # OR
    \G                  # restart from last match position
)                   # end group
.*?                 # 0 or more any character, not greedy
\K                  # forget all we have seen until this position
\b                  # word boundary
m_                  # literally
(?=                 # positive lookahead, make sure we have, after:
    Member\d+           # Member and 1 or more digits
    (?:                 # non capture group
        (?!<myTag>)         # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't <myTag> after
        .                   # any character
    )*?                 # end group, may appear 0 or more times
    <end>           # end tag
)                   # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: This answer does not have enough upvotes, holy cow. I'll be studying this...